# Other reasons for "Sharing" tab missing in folder's properties

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing

I have serious problems sharing any folder on my office PC with Windows 10 because:

- I don't have *Share with...* / *Share* items in folder's context menu,
- the *Sharing* tab is missing in folder's properties,
- clicking on *Advanced sharing...* in *Share with* group in *Share* tab of *This PC* / *File Explorer* ribbon opens folder's properties dialog window with *General* tab displayed and (again) no sign of *Sharing* tab (I have *Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)* option disabled in folders options.

Additional (weird?) observation. It seems that there is some icon missing from *Share* tab:

[image]

(though this could be irrelevant)

Things done so far:

- verified that [ICS service is up and running](https://superuser.com/a/44749/156554) (is it relevant at all -- it was turned off and set to manual start; I changed it to running + autostart and restarted computer; no effect),
- (standard solution) verified that [all registry keys are in places](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/sharing-tab-is-missing-windows) (see below),
- computer was restarted several times.

As for point 2., I have `REG_SZ` key of `{f81e9010-6ea4-11ce-a7ff-00aa003ca9f6}` value in:

- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Sharing`,
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Sharing`,
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Sharing`,
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\LibraryFolder\background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Sharing`,
- `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\UserLibraryFolder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Sharing`

and in a few more places.

The overall Windows 10 and network is configured correctly and working fine. I am able to share a folder, by turning back to "easy" mode (i.e. enabling *Use Sharing Wizard (Recommended)* option in folders options and using sharing wizard). And I can later access shared folder from other computer in my network. So the problem is with missing *Sharing* tab and context menu options.

**Is there any other reason (except for ICS service not running and missing registry entry) for *Sharing* tab not appearing in folder's properties dialog?**

*The biggest suspect*: Recently I've been digging in Windows registry to clean up my totally messed up files' and folders' context menu. I might remove too much, but I am unable to figure out what was that "too much" since all basic entries (according to [basic solution](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/sharing-tab-is-missing-windows)) are in place.

Comment: Check if under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked` you have an item named `{f81e9010-6ea4-11ce-a7ff-00aa003ca9f6}`. If it exists, delete it and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc Bingo! That did it. I think it got added to that list because I was being a tad aggressive with WinAero Tweaker and NirSoft's shell tools while I was disabling/removing other annoying third-party shell-extensions.

Comment: @Dai: Thank you for confirming my comment, so I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if under the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Shell Extensions\Blocked`
you have an item named `{f81e9010-6ea4-11ce-a7ff-00aa003ca9f6}`.

If it exists, delete it and reboot.